# Node.js vs Google App engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, azure, google-compute-engine

I have looked at the following link from Google

[Node.js a and App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket-on-gcp)

I dont understand how App Engine and Node.js is different in scaling. Regarding the link, it is for using socket.io. But why not use only Node.js then? The setup might be the same on Windows Azure, where you have Node.js running on a IIS thread.

But again I don't understand, why you would need the App Engine/IIS layer if Node.js is good at scaling?

Regarding datastore, I have read that the datastore you can have access to from Node.js Compute Engine,  is the same as the one you would use from within App Engine.

Much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: When I read the article you mention, Node.js runs on Compute Engine to service the websockets.

Comment: Right, thanks I meant socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because the compute engine [costs money per time used](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing). It would be wasteful to use that time to wait for simple HTTP requests and database management. Google AppEngine doesn't cost money up to a particular quota, and [charges](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing) differently.

Comment: That is definitely possible, it is a shame if there is no technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm updating my post with new information that I have gathered with time while using Google's App Engine.

When you are using App engine a lot of things are automated.

You don't have to worry about checking server fault and error reporting etc. They do it for you and you can get notified about issues as well depending on options you feed to it.

Load Balancing is entirely done by google app engine therefore you don't need to write long codes for that as well. Google's load balancing is pretty reliable as well.

You can check the logs and all on the go and you don't need to maintain a text file for that as there is a section to access them directly.